# Bottom layer keeps labels on top in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, display, order

I have a small map saved in a GeoPackage file, that includes multiple layers. I added a new csv layer, exported as shapefile, saved and included in the GeoPackage file. No matter what I do, although it is placed the last one, this layer's content (markers and labels) are always on top of the map.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

This is happening in QGIS 3.32.2-Lima, on Mac OS.

Comment: Rendering happens usually  so that the last layer in the rendering queue is rendered last on the top of the previously rendered layers. That is called painter's algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm. Rendering order should not be based on the order in which the tables are stored into the datastore because it may change. The order should be defined explicitly by using layer names in the rendering rules. The rendering engine may also handle labels and markers in a special way and place them always on top.

Comment: I think QGIS is intentionally made to place all labels on the top. I could not find any way from the user interface to override this behavior. The only way is probably to turn off the whole layer.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. I struggled the whole weekend for a solution, but I coundn't find any. There might be something though, but I'm not that experienced.